# How do I plot a vector of values in the specified order in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, mean, col

I have a vector of values (column means) that all belong to a certain question. I ams trying to plot the values on the y-axis and the question name on the x-axis. My data frame looks like this:

```
> colMeansDf
    colMeans Question
Q2  3.468240       Q2
Q3  3.677858       Q3
Q4  3.147913       Q4
Q5  3.072595       Q5
Q6  2.382940       Q6
Q7  2.556261       Q7
Q8  2.852087       Q8
Q9  2.663339       Q9
Q10 2.816697      Q10
Q11 4.735027      Q11
Q12 3.820327      Q12
Q13 3.000000      Q13
Q14 3.114338      Q14
Q15 2.806715      Q15
Q16 2.238657      Q16
Q17 3.228675      Q17
Q18 2.023593      Q18
Q19 3.986388      Q19
Q20 2.913793      Q20
Q21 2.611615      Q21
Q22 2.446461      Q22
```

Now when I try to use `ggplot` to visualize this data `ggplot` seems to change the order of the data frame for some reason, and instead of starting at Q2 and ending at Q22, I get an x-axis that moves from Q10 to Q19, Q2, Q20, Q21, Q22, Q23 and that from Q3 to Q9.

My code so far is this:

```
ggplot(colMeansDf, aes(x = Questions, y = colMeans)) +
    geom_point(alpha = .6) +
    labs(x = "Question", y = "Average Reponse") +
    geom_hline(yintercept = mean(colMeansDf$colMeans), color = "red") +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(1, 7), breaks = 1:7)
```

Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi It's sorting the Question names as strings. You can add an index (with just the question number) and use this index to rearrange the question names numerically.

```
colMeansDf <- colMeansDf %>% 
  mutate(index = as.numeric(substr(Questions,2,nchar(as.character(Questions)))),
         Questions = factor(Questions, levels=((colMeansDf %>% arrange(index))$Questions)))

ggplot(colMeansDf, aes(x = Questions, y = colMeans)) +
  geom_point(alpha = .6) +
  labs(x = "Question", y = "Average Reponse") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = mean(colMeansDf$colMeans), color = "red") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(1, 7), breaks = 1:7)
```